# NoClassDefFoundError when using JAX-WS in an OSGI 4.2 bundle

Tags: java, osgi, jax-ws, cytoscape, karaf

I've been tasked with updating a plugin for [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), a biological visualization software platform, to the latest version of the Cytoscape API. Cytoscape 3.x uses an OSGI framework (Karaf 2.2.x, I think) to interface with its plugins (which are now called "apps").

The problem is that the plugin/app uses JAX-WS to communicate with an external server, and JAX-WS seems to have problems with loading classes in the OSGI environment.

Here is a snippet of the problematic code:

```
public class AnatServerService extends Service {
    @WebEndpoint(name = "AnatServerPort")
    public AnatServerIfc getServerPort() {
        AnatServerIfc port =  super.getPort(new QName("network", "AnatServerPort"), AnatServerIfc.class);
        ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, path);
    return port;
    }
}
```

And here is the resulting exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Header not found by AnatApp [168]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createProxy(UnknownSource)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Unknown Source)
    at anat.ws.AnatServerService.getServerPort(AnatServerService.java:36)
    at anat.task.AvailableNetworksTask.getAvailableNetworks(AvailableNetworksTask.java:39)
    at anat.task.AvailableNetworksTask.run(AvailableNetworksTask.java:62)
    at org.cytoscape.work.internal.sync.SyncTaskManager.execute(SyncTaskManager.java:86)
    at anat.view.BackgroundDefinitionDialog$AvailableNetworksSwingWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundDefinitionDialog.java:1544)
    at anat.view.BackgroundDefinitionDialog$AvailableNetworksSwingWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundDefinitionDialog.java:1535)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can confirm that this code *does* work outside of OSGI.

Any suggestions? I've tried experimenting with embedding the JAX-WS API and/or implementation classes directly into the bundle using `Embed-Dependency`, but that didn't help. I've also tried playing with the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` and `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` properties, to no avail. It is possible that I'm doing something wrong, though.

I'm afraid that OSGI might have some fundamental incompatibility with the Reflection API being used to create that header. But surely it can't be impossible to run a web service client in this environment, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem. It turns out I had edited the `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` property in the wrong file - `config.properties` instead of `custom.properties`.

This is still a problem in the long term, though. I'd like to be able to distribute this bundle without requiring users to edit config files.

Comment: Unfortunately, my short term problems aren't over yet either. New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706565/jax-ws-unmarshals-empty-objects-when-in-an-osgi-environment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like JAX-WS is dynamically weaving dependencies into your bundle that were not present at build time. Because these dependencies are dynamic, the build tooling doesn't find them and doesn't generate an `Import-Package` statement for them.

Specifically your bundle has a dependency on the package `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message`. You never wanted or asked for that dependency, but JAX-WS added it for you anyway. How nice of it!

Your question suggests that you are using Maven with the maven-bundle-plugin to build your bundle. Therefore you need to add something like this to your pom:

```
<Import-Package>
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message,
    *
</Import-Package>
```

Note that there may be other packages that need to be added to this list... you will probably find out about them after adding this one. Again, because these are dynamically weaved-in dependencies it's impossible to get a full list of them in advance.

With regard to your final question. You're right, it's certainly not impossible to run a web service client in this environment! However OSGi does tend to expose the invalid assumptions and bad coding practices that are typically found in crappy libraries like JAX-WS.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I tried experimenting with `Import-Package` too, but I set it aside pretty quickly. I probably should have tried more. 

Here's the result of that:
`org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle AnatApp [168]: Unable to resolve 168.4: missing requirement [168.4] package; (package=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message)`

Perhaps I need to combine this approach with one of the things I already tried.

Comment: Turns out `Import-Package` wasn't necessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding the following line to Felix's `config.properties` file solved the problem:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.sun.xml.internal.ws.*
```