# JAX-WS fails to unmarshal in an OSGI environment

Tags: java, soap, osgi, jax-ws, cytoscape

I've been tasked with updating a plugin for [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), a biological visualization software platform, to the latest version of the Cytoscape API. Cytoscape 3.x uses an OSGI framework (Karaf 2.2.x, I think) to interface with its plugins (which are now called "apps").

The plugin/app is actually a client that uses JAX-WS to communicate with an external server. But for some reason, despite the absence of any error messages, it fails to unmarshal the SOAP messages that it's getting. The desired objects are created with the default constructor, but their fields remain empty.

I can confirm that the XML *does* arrive from the server in one piece. I can also confirm that this same code works in a non-OSGI environment. Furthermore, enabling the `jaxb.debug` JVM option for both the OSGI and non-OSGI versions shows that JAXB appears to be doing the exact same things behind the scenes in both cases.

So, I have no idea what's going on here. Any ideas?

**Update:**

After further investigation, I've determined that the problem may not have anything directly to do with JAX-WS at all. I saved the SOAP message that arrives from the web service as an XML file on my hard drive. Attempting to directly unmarshal it, without touching the web service at all, caused this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;
```

Once again, this same code works fine in a standalone non-OSGI environment. Very strange.

Comment: Have you enabled the standard out and debug level Log4j logging as described [here](http://wiki.cytoscape.org/Cytoscape_3/CoreDevelopment/Debugging)?  Depending on how they have logging configured out of the box, they may be eating warnings and errors.

Comment: Nope, there are no warnings or errors or anything out of the ordinary in the log, even at TRACE logging level.

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.

I added the [Apache ServiceMix Stax API 1.2 bundle](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.stax-api-1.2/2.3.0) to the Cytoscape OSGI container, and then used `Import-Package` to import its `javax.xml.stream` package into my own bundle, making sure to require version 1.2 and up.

It seems that Cytoscape by default provides an out of date (Java 5?) version of `javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory`, and that this was the source of all my problems. It didn't actually make my manual unmarshalling code work (there were still some weird API/implementation version mismatches that threw exceptions) but the original web service code did.

Answer (score 1):

The built in jaxws support of the jdk is not compatible to OSGi.

You could try to install Apache CXF on karaf. There is a karaf feature for it. So installation is pretty simple. See http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi

Comment: Assuming I did that, what code changes would be required?

Comment: Depends a bit on how you use jaxws today. CXF supports the standard JAXWs API like Endpoint.publish. So if you use this no change is required. On the other hand CXF provides special support for e.g. blueprint. So it depends if you want to use those.